# How to prevent the dreaded KSOAP2 Connection Time Out in Android

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2, connection-timeout

I have been trying to prevent a KSOAP2 call from timing out when requesting data from my Axis2 Web Service through Android but have been unable to do so.

**A background on the Web Service.**

My Web Service is running on Apache Tomcat server and is used to return real-time information for stations. When I try through a browser it works as expected and on website it also works as expected.

**The Problem**

However when I try to use the same method in my Android application sometimes I will get the following stack track error. Other times the request will be successful. At times the request will time out immediately and other times it will wait around a minute before timing out.

**Devices**

I have tried it through a Samsung Galaxy SII (Platform 2.3.3) and on a Samsung Galaxy SI (Platform 2.2.2) using WiFi and using 3G with the same results. However it never times out when using it through the emulator (Platform 2.2).

**My Code**

```
String NAMESPACE = "http://service.domain.ie";
String URL = "http://www.myhost.com/axis2/services/RealTime?wsdl";
String METHOD_NAME = "getStationData";
String SOAP_ACTION = "RealTime";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("stationType", getStationType());
request.addProperty("stationApiCode", getApiCode());

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport;

SoapObject response = null;

try {
        androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,60000); // Tried Setting the Timeout to 1 Minute
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
        response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Stack Trace Error**

```
04-13 13:07:18.015: W/System.err(9249): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
04-13 13:07:18.015: W/System.err(9249):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:461)
04-13 13:07:18.015: W/System.err(9249):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:85)
04-13 13:07:18.015: W/System.err(9249):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:65)
04-13 13:07:18.015: W/System.err(9249):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:140)
04-13 13:07:18.015: W/System.err(9249):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:225)
04-13 13:07:18.020: W/System.err(9249):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.readLine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:660)
04-13 13:07:18.020: W/System.err(9249):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.readResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:690)
04-13 13:07:18.020: W/System.err(9249):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1040)
04-13 13:07:18.020: W/System.err(9249):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:512)
04-13 13:07:18.020: W/System.err(9249):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.openInputStream(ServiceConnectionSE.java:113)
04-13 13:07:18.020: W/System.err(9249):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:160)
04-13 13:07:18.050: W/System.err(9249):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
04-13 13:07:18.050: W/System.err(9249):     at ie.smartcommuter.models.Station.getRealTimeData(Station.java:123)
04-13 13:07:18.050: W/System.err(9249):     at ie.smartcommuter.controllers.tabcontents.StationRealtimeActivity$1.run(StationRealtimeActivity.java:95)
04-13 13:07:18.050: W/System.err(9249):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

I have updated KSOAP2 from 2.4 to 2.5.7 and tried to set the timeout limit but I have been unsuccessful so far. So to get to my question:

**Has anybody else had this problem and if so how did they resolve it?**

Comment: Have to try with Timeout with `TIMEOUT=20000;` in your `new HttpTransportSE(URL,60000); `

Answer (score 0):

when the timeout kicks in it will throw SocketTimeoutException.

you should catch it in you try-catch and handle the timeout as you like